# Why is the SELECT command at the beginning of the procedure instead of at the end?

Tags: sql

I'm used to writing lines of code and having them execute in order, from up to down. I believe this is how nearly most programming languages work.

In SQL, if I understand it correctly, one first must create a table by performing some table operations (`FROM` to choose the starting tables, `JOIN` to combine them in various ways, `WHERE` to filter out some rows, `GROUP BY` to filter our duplicates, etc.).

Once you have your outputted table, you use `SELECT` to perform one final table operation: eliminate the undesired fields.

So I would expect `FROM` to be the first line of code, and `SELECT` to be the very last line of code. But `SELECT` is always first for some reason...

Is there an explanation as to why SQL commands are written in reverse?

Comment: the names you provide in SELECT (as AS) are/can be used in further statements. Knowing what you need up-front also provides simple optimizations, though I would imagine these days the queries are fully parsed and statically analyzed anyway, yet the syntax remains.

Comment: It's derived from ANSI-SQL syntax. Why would you suggest they are *written in reverse*? Perhaps it's a reverse syntax compared to what you are used to, but again it's simply syntax.

Comment: sql is not a programming language.  It is a query language.  Select... from... is ONE SQL statement.

Comment: Gordon's answer and these comments solved my confusion. SQL doesn't read like a programming language because it's not one. Or at least, it's not a procedural one.

Comment: I doubt if a proper answer exists... nobody knows what the person was thinking when they were preparing the specs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

SQL has a standard and that standard specifies the ordering.

You are missing something fundamental about SQL: it is a *descriptive* language, not a *procedural* language. That is, a SQL query describes the result set being produced, not the steps that must be taken to produce those results.

So, there is no "execution order" for the SQL clause. All taken together describe the results.

That said, there might be notes going back to the original development of SQL. My best guess is that the first thing one sees on a tabular report are the column headings, and that is why the `SELECT` is first.  I appreciate the elegance of having `FROM` first (because `FROM` defines the table and column aliases used throughout the query). But that simply is not how the language is defined.

Answer (score 0):

This is the structure of syntax used by SQL, like semantics of any programming language.

`SELECT` is basically used where we need to filter and fetch particular data. Then, `FROM` is used which refers to table.

It's used in normal SQL queries also for the same purpose.
In terms of procedure we use `SELECT` as below:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE
SelectAllStudent
As 
SELECT * FROM students
GO
```

And then we execute procedure as:

```
EXEC SelectAllStudent
```